# In d3 line chart not able to see the month name if the date is last day of the month

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, charts

I am using react, d3 chart to generate the line chart. I used d3.min and d3.max to generate the min and max values for both x and y axis. The data for  the xAxis all ways comes  in the string format lets say "2017-12-31" and I am using timeparse to parse the string into date format and pass it to x axis.

Now the xAxis scale shows as Jan, Feb, March ....

```
    g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3Axis.axisBottom(x).tickFormat(d3Time.timeFormat("%b")))
```

Now when ever the minimum value of xAxis is last date of month it was not showing up in the scale of xAxis.

For example if the the minimum value is '2018-07-01' Then axis scale will be showing "July, Aug, Sep, Oct"

but if the minimum value is '2018-07-31' then axis scale will be showing  "Aug, Sep, Oct"

The data is formatted in such way that the dates of all previously months will be showing as the last of the month.

```
ex: [{date: '2018-07-31', value: 10}, 
     {date: '2018-08-31', value: 10},
     {date: '2018-09-30', value: 10},
     {date: '2018-10-31', value: 10}]
```

Is it possible to show the Month Name even if the minimal value is last of the month.

Answer (score 1):

[d3.scaleTime().nice](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#time_nice) is what you'll be looking for in this case.

Quoting the docs:

> This method typically modifies the scale’s domain, and may only extend the bounds to the nearest round value. Nicing is useful if the domain is computed from data, say using extent, and may be irregular.

**Example without using `nice` method**

```js
var data = [{date: '2018-07-31', value: 10}, 
     {date: '2018-08-31', value: 10},
     {date: '2018-09-30', value: 10},
     {date: '2018-10-31', value: 10}];

var parseTime = d3.timeParse('%Y-%m-%d');

data.forEach(function (d) {
 d.date = parseTime(d.date); 
});
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width', 500).attr('height', 400);

var gAxis = svg.append('g').classed('x axis', true);

var xScale = d3.scaleTime().domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.date)).range([10, 490]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b"));

gAxis.call(xAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

**Example using the scale's `nice` method**

```js
var data = [{date: '2018-07-31', value: 10}, 
     {date: '2018-08-31', value: 10},
     {date: '2018-09-30', value: 10},
     {date: '2018-10-31', value: 10}];

var parseTime = d3.timeParse('%Y-%m-%d');

data.forEach(function (d) {
 d.date = parseTime(d.date); 
});
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width', 500).attr('height', 400);

var gAxis = svg.append('g').classed('x axis', true);

var xScale = d3.scaleTime().domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.date)).range([10, 490]).nice();

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b"));

gAxis.call(xAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps.